# How to copy matching properties from one object to another

Tags: typescript

I have these two objects:

```
obj1 = {a: '', b: ''}
obj2 = {a: '1', b: '2', c: '3'}
```

I want to copy all matching properties from `obj2` to `obj1`. What is the best way of doing that in Typescript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 17):

> what is the best way of doing that in typescript

Same as in JavaScript. Just use `Object.keys`

The following code moves stuff from obj2 to obj1:

```
let obj1 = {a: '', b: ''}
let obj2 = {a: '1', b: '2', c: '3'}

Object.keys(obj2).forEach(key=>obj1[key]=obj2[key]);
```

For any condition like must not already be in obj1 etc you can do that check in the `forEach`

Comment: don't you think there must be some conditional statement to check if key exist in obj1 or not. e.g. obj1.hasOwnProperty(key);

Comment: @basarat do you have the same **copy only matching properties** but a deep traversal?  I am always facing this issue when loading user settings structure from some local storage. I would like to start with my latest object structure loaded with defaults and only copy the matching key's values recursively from the object loaded from storage.  I cannot seem to find the right post for this.  Thank you.

Comment: The code in this answer is incomplete, as it ignores the OP's request to only copy matching properties. The following should be added: `if (key in obj1)`.

Comment: Maybe TSC has become more strict, but I get a type error (ts:7053) for this code, complaining about there being no indexer on the object types.

Comment: TSC strictness is an option

Comment: Copying and pasting this code into the typescript playground (typescriptlang.org/play) results in multiple compile errors.  This seems to only "work" insofar as you disable all the relevant type checks in TypeScript; you might as well just be writing JavaScript.

Answer (score 16):

If you don't mind any keys of `obj2` not exist in `obj1`, a clearer way is using `Object.assign(obj1, obj2)`:

Answer (score 2):

I think @basarat meant to iterate over the target properties not the source ones like this

```
function CopyMatchingKeyValues(Target, Source) {
    return Object.keys(Target).forEach(key => {
        if (Source[key] !== undefined)
            Target[key] = Source[key];
    });
}
```

[image]

Actually he is testing for key matching it won't matter.

- For performance we probably want to pick the shortest list of the keys.

Comment: Please post code as [text rather than images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: This gives me ERROR ts:7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I was able to satisfy TS compiler was like below, but my eyes bleed when looking at this

```
Object.keys(source).forEach(key => {
    if (destination.hasOwnProperty(key))
        destination[key as keyof Destination] = source[key as keyof Source] as never;
});
```