# How to assign values to object that has similar keys?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

just wanted to avoid if statements is there way to assign values to object if they have similar keys in response instead of checking each object with if ?

what could be efficient approach here ?

main.ts

```
  public responsehandler(@Body()data: any): any {
        const response: Idetails = {} as Idetails;
        if (data.details === undefined || data.details === null) {
           return data;
        }
        if (data.details) {
            if (data.details.primary) {
                response.details.primary.beginningBalance = data.details.primary.beginningBalance;
                response.details.primary.endingBalance = data.details.primary.endingBalance;
            }

            if (data.details.secondary) {
                response.details.secondary.beginningBalance = data.details.secondary.beginningBalance;
                response.details.secondary.endingBalance = data.details.secondary.endingBalance;

            }

        }
        return response;
    }
```

interface.ts

```
export interface Idetails {
 primary:balanceDetails;
 secondary: balanceDetails;
}

export interface balanceDetails {
     beginningBalance: string;
     endingBalance: string;
}
```

data

```
details: {
 primary: {
   beginningBalance: 458,
   endingBalance: 890
 }, 

 secondary: {
   beginningBalance: 47,
   endingBalance: 871
 }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy matching properties from one object to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36441682/how-to-copy-matching-properties-from-one-object-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/hasOwnProperty

You could try this approach:

```
public responsehandler(@Body()data: any): any {
    const response: Idetails = {} as Idetails;
    if (!data.details) {
         return data;
    }

    for (const key in response.details) {
            if (data.details.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    response.details[key] = data.details[key];
            }
    }

    return response;
}
```

You should check more validations or conditions to make it work for you.

Comment: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Idetails' has no index signature

Comment: Watch out: It might not be an issue but this copy is less 'deep' then the one in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is just to avoid if statements, you could rewrite it like so:

```js
// in js (sorry not a ts user)

function responseHandler(data) {
  return data.details == null ? data : {details: {...data.details}};
}

console.log(responseHandler({details: {primary: {beginningBalance: 0, endingBalance: 1}}}));

console.log(responseHandler({details: {secondary: {beginningBalance: 0, endingBalance: 1}}}));

console.log(responseHandler({noDetails: 'oopsy'}));
```