# trying to assign values to my interface object if it has similar keys?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have data coming that needs to map to the interface I declared for the response when I assign keys to object it shows error `TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Idetails' has no index signature.` any idea to fix it?

main.ts

```
public Responsehandler(@Body() data: any): any {
    const response: Idetails = {} as Idetails;
    if (data.details === undefined || data.details === null) {
        return data;
    }
    if (data.details) {
        response.details.lineOfBusiness = "PBM";
        Object.keys(data.details).forEach((key) => {
            response.details[key] = data.details[key]
        });
    }
    return response;
}
```

interface.ts

```
export interface Idetails {
 primary:balanceDetails;
 secondary: balanceDetails;
}

export interface balanceDetails {
     beginningBalance: string;
     endingBalance: string;
}
```

Comment: What means "map to interface"? I assume you want ``response`` variable to have ``primary`` and ``secondary`` property?

Comment: because primary and secondary both has similar keys so i want response to map keys from data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign values to object that has similar keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52933808/how-to-assign-values-to-object-that-has-similar-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're running into the issue where `Object.keys(obj)` returns `string[]` instead of something like `(keyof typeof obj)[]`.   It's a [common issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20503) that gets [reported](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15295) a [lot](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15627).  The reason `Object.keys()` has to return `string[]` is because types in TypeScript are *open* in the sense that an object has to have *at least* the properties described by a type for it to match.  So the only type-safe return value is `string[]`.  See [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208) for more information.

This means that assuming `data.details` is of type `Idetails` (I don't see that in your code... `data` is just of type `any`; you should tighten that up), all you know is that it has *at least* the `primary` and `secondary` properties, but it might have more.  For example, `data.details` might be

```
const details = {
  primary: { beginningBalance: "$0", endingBalance: "$200" },
  secondary: { beginningBalance: "25¢", endingBalance: "10¢" },
  tertiary: { beginningBalance: "₿100,000", endingBalance: "₿0.001" }
}
```

And therefore `key` is not a valid index into `response.details`, since `key` might be `"teritary"`.

---

The easiest way to deal with this is just to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) that `Object.keys(data.details)` returns just the keys you know about.  Sure, it's possible that at runtime there will be extra keys, and the code will just copy those extra properties into `response.details`... which is probably harmless since it doesn't stop `response.details` from being a valid `Idetails`.  Here's how you could do it:

```
(Object.keys(data.details) as (keyof Idetails)[]).forEach((key) => {
  response.details[key] = data.details[key]; // okay
});
```

Notice that we are using the `as` keyword to assert that `Object.keys(data.details)` returns a `(keyof Idetails)[]`.  Now, `key` is inferred to be `"primary" | "secondary"`, and the compiler is happy with the assignment.

---

There are other ways to deal with the issue in the case where you want to prevent copying extra properties, such as manually specifying the array of keys to copy without inspecting `data.details` at all:

```
// helper function to narrow array to string literals
const stringLiterals = <T extends string[]>(...args: T) => args;

// stringLiterals("primary", "secondary") is inferred as type ["primary", "secondary"]
stringLiterals("primary", "secondary").forEach((key) => {
  response.details[key] = data.details[key]; // okay
});
```

This is now completely type safe and doesn't require any type assertions, but it might be more trouble than it's worth.

---

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: i tried your Object.keys solutions getting this error  `Array type using 'T[]' is forbidden for non-simple types. Use 'Array<T>' instead. (array-type)`

Comment: `(Object.keys(data.details) as Array<keyof ICaremarkResponse>)` resolved tslint issue

Comment: Those are equivalent;  tslint can be configured to report or not report that warning but it’s a matter of style, not correctness.

Comment: not sure it still says can not set property of "primary" undefined

Comment: I can't reproduce that; is that a runtime error?  It is likely to be a separate issue from what you've posted about; please review what constitutes a [mcve].

Comment: thanks for the help yes it is run time error let be dig into this